# date format al exportar a excel cambia

Tags: c#

Tengo este código para exportar a [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) un DataGridView:

```
 {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    app.Visible = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    ws.Name = "Hedging";
    ws.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    // storing header part in Excel
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        ws.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";
        ws.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        ws.Cells[1, i].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue);

    }

    // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
        {               
            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        }

        int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage);
    }

    ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    wb.SaveAs(textBox2.Text, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

Mi duda es al abrir el DataGridView esta con formato *`dd/MM/yy`*, pero al exportarlo a excel se convierte a *`dd/MM/yy  HH:mm:ss`*.

Solo quiero que aparezca *`dd/MM/yyyy`*.

¿Cómo puedo establecer el formato *`dd/MM/yyyy`* al exportar la información a un archivo Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un caso similar al trabajar con fechas, tenia un DataGridView que se llena con una consulta a la BD y contenia campos con fecha, como en otros foros que estuve investigando también me cambiaba el dia por el mes por ejemplo si tenia en el DataGridView 03/01/2019 al exportar al excel se pasaba como 01/03/2019. En mi caso siempre llenaba la fila numero 1 del excel con los header del DataGridView

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
```

Después de realizar esto configuraba el formato de las columnas con campos de fecha utilizando NumberFormat, para el tipo de formato que tu quieras https://support.office.com/es-es/article/c%C3%B3digos-de-formato-de-n%C3%BAmero-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=es-ES&rs=es-HN&ad=419 yo lo converti a texto para que se incrustara en el excel tal cual esta en el DataGridView

```
columns = new string[3] { "A", "G", "H" };
worksheet = cambiarFormatoColumn(worksheet, "@", columns);
```

Yo use metodo por que realizaba varios reportes y todos tenian campos con fecha en diferentes columnas

```
public _Worksheet cambiarFormatoColumn(_Worksheet worksheet, string format, string[] colums)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colums.GetLength(0); i++)
            worksheet.Columns[colums[i]].NumberFormat = format;

        return worksheet;
    }
```

Y pues ya al final llenar las celdas restantes

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa [NumberFormat](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm):

Ejemplo:

```
string FRM_EXCEL_FECHA = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // o el formato que deseas:
ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].NumberFormat = FRM_EXCEL_FECHA;
ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de resolverlo. Antes de crear tu celda, debes establecer el tipo de formato:

```
//Variable para crear formatos
IDataFormat format = workbook.CreateDataFormat();

//Establecer valor numérico en formato deseado en una variable
ICellStyle EstiloFechaCorta = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
EstiloFechaCorta.DataFormat = format.GetFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

//Al momento de crear tu celda correspondiente establece los estilos y al final le asignas el valor
fila = 1; //valor de la fila
col = 1; //valor de la columna
//creas una variable para la fila
row = excelSheet.CreateRow(fila);

//Creas una fila de tipo numérico y la guardas en una variable
ICell CeldaFechaInicio = row.CreateCell(col, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric);

//A esa variable le asignas el estilo que necesitas mostrar
CeldaFechaInicio.CellStyle = EstiloFechaCorta;

//Finalmente le das el valor a la variable
CeldaFechaInicio.SetCellValue(DateTime.Parse("2022-03-08").Date);
```

Listo, te mostrará solo el formato que necesitas

Answer (score -1):

Dale ese formato a tu columna

```
Range rango = (Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Cells[1,1];
rango.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
```